# C++ on VS10 facedetection ERRORs

Tags: c++

i'm new to C++ and VS2010... and i need some help!
i downloaded an open source code "visual-control" which do some face detection using openCV...
I'm trying to run the project on Visual Studio 2010 and i followed the instructions ( including libraries, includes .... after installing QT,TBB,openCV,cMake ... ) but i'm still receiving the following error

Any help is appreciated!

```
    "'Moc'ing visualcontrol.h...
  1>  Moc'ing webcamwidget.h...
  1>ClCompile:
  1>  detailedfacedetector.cpp
  1>  facedetector.cpp
  1>  eigenfacerecognizer.cpp
  1>  trainerimage.cpp
  1>  logger.cpp
  1>  main.cpp
  1>  moc_visualcontrol.cpp
  1>  moc_webcamwidget.cpp
  1>  framecapture.cpp
  1>  detector.cpp
  1>  visualcontrol.cpp
  1>  webcamwidget.cpp
  1>  Generating Code...
  1>  qrc_visualcontrol.cpp
  1>logger.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1QString@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall       QString::~QString(void)) imported in function "public: void __thiscall Logger::log      (class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class       std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?log@Logger@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?      $allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
  1>visualcontrol.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??1QString@@QAE@XZ (public:       __thiscall QString::~QString(void)) imported
  1>webcamwidget.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol
  ........... .. . . . . .. . .
  1>webcamwidget.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public:       class QString & __thiscall QString::setNum(float,char,int)" (__imp_?      setNum@QString@@QAEAAV1@MDH@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall       gui::WebcamWidget::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?      paintEvent@WebcamWidget@gui@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
  1>webcamwidget.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec                  (dllimport)             public:       class QString & __this'"
```

Comment: ummm... can you show some code.... without it, accurate answer can not be given..

Comment: the code contains no syntax errors, it is downloaded from:
https://code.google.com/p/visual-control/downloads/detail?name=visual-control.zip&can=2&q=

Anyways here are some line from the visualcontrol.cpp class:

cv::Mat frame;
cognition::Detector::RectVector faces;

faceDetector->loadCascade(DetailedFaceDetector::EYES, "haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml");

QMessageBox::information(this, "Recognizer is not trained", "Recognizer is not trained or....

Comment: You might need to add some external dependencies.. Properties > Config > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and select the ddls required...

Answer (score 0):

OK my problem is solved, the problem was with the QT add-in in VS. thanks anws guys :)